# Android: ArrayAdapter out of bounds crash on getView after refresh

Tags: android

I'm currently having a crashing issue with scrolling down a listview and pressing refresh quickly. Eclipse is giving me

```
11-25 23:58:51.511: E/AndroidRuntime(29736): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
```

on this code:

```
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Link>(getActivity(), R.layout.link_item,
            mLinkManager.getLinks()) {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLinkManager.getLinks().size();
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return mLinkManager.getLinks().get(position).getId().hashCode();
        }

        public Link getItem(int position) {
            return mLinkManager.getLinks().get(position);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.link_item, null);
            }

            Link link = mLinkManager.getLinks().get(position);

            // Set textview stuff from links here

            return convertView;
        };
    };

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

The crash occurs on the last line. Is there a way to stop getView() method once I press refresh? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private class RefreshLinksTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing...");
        if (mIsRefreshing || mIsDownloading)
            cancel(true);
        mIsRefreshing = true;
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mLinkManager.refreshLinks();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } 
        else {
            createAdapter();
        }
        mIsRefreshing = false;
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting crash on this line??  Link link = mLinkManager.getLinks().get(position);

Comment: position is 1 , it should be 0.

Comment: have you implemented the `getItemId` and `getItem(position)` method ?

Comment: Right. I basically wiped the links array in LinkManager since I refreshed it. For the getItemId, is that for the Adapter? The mLinkManager.getLinks() is just an array.

Comment: I guess refresh is not a problem. Problem is different. **Post whole code of adapter**

Comment: Yes its for adapter only.

Comment: Updated with adapter code and also added the refresh task

Comment: When RefreshLinksTask is being called?

Comment: I set it so that it's being called whenever the action bar button is called. I do recreate the linkManager object before executing the RefreshTask. Is this an issue?

Comment: what do you mean by "whenever the action bar button is called"???

Comment: Please note that you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` immediately after changing items in backing list. My suggestion would be to return a list of `Link`s from `doInBackground()`and set it from `onPostExecute()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh: Thank you. I followed your suggestion of refactoring my AsyncTask so that I only change the datasource at the last moment and notify right after. It seems not to crash anymore.

Comment: Glad to help, posting it as answer so others can benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` immediately after changing items in backing list. My suggestion would be to return a list of Links from `doInBackground()` and set it from `onPostExecute()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.